# How to implement a 2-to-4 mux

Tags: multiplexer

Our logical circuit teacher asked us to draw the diagram of inside a 2-to-4 multiplexer and said it's going to be in our final exam. How is this circuit possible? I thought a mux always goes from a larger number of inputs to a lower number of outputs.

Comment: 2-to-4 would be a decoder/demultiplexer, wouldn't it?

Comment: @DaveTweed Yeah, I know, and I told that to teacher, but he kept saying that it's possible and you should find the solution!

Comment: @DaveTweed someone mentioned that it's maybe a 8-to-4 multiplexer and those 8 inputs are coming in 2*4 lines. I don't know, I just want to pass this course!

Comment: Just a thought...Did you question him in front of the whole class?  He may have just gotten defensive, and might consider your argument if you meet him during open office hours if it's an option.  Come prepared with symbols/schematics/descriptions/truth tables for the cases you think it might be.

Comment: @Justin I'm sure he meant it! We even did draw a circuit for it with 8 `and`s for input and an `or` for output, and he said it's partly correct but you have to correct it, add details to it and describe it for me!

Comment: As Dave said a 2-to-4 would commonly be called a *de*multiplexer, so either you did not pass the correct question to us, or your teacher attaches some (slightly?) non-standard meaning to the word multiplexer. Exam questions often need to be understood the context of the classes, so without access to that info it will be difficult for us to interpret the question.

Answer (score 1):

A "single" multiplexer is a device which forwards a selectable input to a fixed output.  Sometimes multiplexers are grouped together, such that one might have a chip with two groups of four inputs and two outputs; one input from the first group is forwarded to the first output, and one from the second group is sent to the second output.

My guess would be that what the instructor is asking for is a device which interprets a pair of inputs as a two-bit number and then uses that to select one of four data inputs to be forwarded.  There are a variety of ways one could construct such a thing.  The simplest is to generate four signals--one for each data input--indicating which input is active.  Then "AND" each data input with its corresponding enable pin.  If any of the AND gates is outputting high, that means it is enabled and the appropriate data input is high.  If none of them is outputting high, that means the data input of the one that's enabled is low.

Incidentally, it may be helpful to define multiplexer, encoder, decoder, demultiplexer, and switch.

A multiplexer is a device which forwards a selected input; typically, the number of the input is expressed as a binary number and is generated from some other device.

An encoder is a device which looks at a significant number of inputs (generally at least 3--often 8 or more) and, if one is active, outputs the identity of the active input using some smaller number of outputs.  A typical pattern would be an 8-input multiplexer which has an output that indicates whether any input is active, and three outputs that together output a 3-bit number indicating which input is active.  Some encoders may behave oddly if more than one input is active; others will identify the highest-priority one according to some ranking.

A decoder is a device which uses some small number of pins to identify which pin among some larger set should be activated.  Most commonly, the smaller number of pins represents a binary number, so a 3-to-8 decoder would use a 3-bit binary number to select from among 8 outputs to activate.  Typically, decoders will have a "master-enable" which will determine whether any outputs should be active.  Connecting a an encoder to a decoder will cause the decoder's outputs to mirror the encoder's inputs whenever zero or one of those inputs are active.

A demultiplexer is, generally, a device that can be used with a multiplexer to "reconstitute" its inputs (analogous to what a decoder would do with signals from an encoder).  Note that because a multiplexer relies on some other device to tell it which signals to output, and then only outputs a single bit, a demultiplexer must have some way of knowing what outputs state is represented by that bit.  Depending upon how those signals are generated, the demultiplexing device may have to operate somewhat differently; consequently, rather than using the term "demultiplexer" to describe a chip, one would more typically use a more specific description such as an "addressable latch".

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the answer, but perhaps if you think about these questions this will help.

1) do you know what a cross point switch is?
- isn't that an N:N mux?
- do they allow any 2 or more of the inputs to go to a common output?
   - if so, is this advantageous?
   - if not, how to do they accomplish the blocking/ no intersecting aspect.

2) do you understand how to do a 1:4 demux?

3) how would you implement a N:N cross point using N 1:N demuxes?
- do you think you'd need to have blocking circuits or is it OK to short the outputs together?